# Is idle thread taking CPU execute time in Java Executors?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, cpu-time

When I have this code in an application:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

but I never use this thread pool. Will the idle threads consume CPU time? If so - why?

Comment: No. The idle thread doesn't consume CPU time (although starting the pool does take time, and it does consume memory).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If I am not mistaken, calling that method will not really **start** the pool. See my answer.

Comment: Just wondering : is there anything preventing you from accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 5):

No, these threads are created lazily, or 'on-demand'. As stated in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) (emphasis mine):

> **On-demand construction**
>
> By default, even core threads are initially created and started *only when new tasks arrive*

Java provides methods to override this default and allow for eager creation, namely [`prestartCoreThread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartCoreThread()) and [`prestartAllCoreThreads`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartAllCoreThreads()).

---

Once threads are actually created, idle ones (generally) won't take CPU time as there is no reason for them to be scheduled on a core when they have no work to do.

They will still hold on to some memory however, for their stack and whatnot.

Answer (score 4):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) states:

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks.

This might lead to assume: we don't know exactly. But as the other answer clearly finds - we can know, and the implementation is actually fully lazy. Thus:

```
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

does not even cause a lot of setup. The implementation would be free to wait for any

```
 service.submit(...
```

to happen.

On the other hand, that thread pool *could* (theoretically)  be created immediately, and also 4 OS threads could be created. If the later is the case, all those threads would be idle'ing, so they should **not** consume any CPU resources.

But of course, as Elliott is correctly pointing out, that initial step of creating the pool and (potentially) creating 1 to 4 threads requires CPU activity.

And of course: *threads* are a OS resource. So even when they "only exist" and do nothing; they have that "cost". Where again, it might depend on the OS if that could ever turn into a problem (like reaching some "maximum number of existing threads" limit).

Finally: as this got me curious, I had a look into the current Java8 source code (from [newFixedThreadPoo()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) and [ThreadPoolExcecutor()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#ThreadPoolExecutor.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Clong%2Cjava.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%2Cjava.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue%29) down into [DefaultThreadFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.DefaultThreadFactory)). If I am not mistaken: those constructors only **prepare** for thread creation.

So: the "current" implementation is "fully" lazy; and if you really only call `newFixedThreadPool()` without ever using the resulting ExecutorService ... **nothing** happens (in terms of new threads being created).